# Meaning of notation (_()) in C code

Tags: c

Looking at the source codes I came across this notation:

```
(void) puts (_("Invalid login time"));
```

what is this `(_())` notation supposed to mean?

Comment: `_(s)` is  macro defined somewhere in your code

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I doubt it's his code, since it's from libgettext.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes you are correct, probably OP is working with some open source project. I saw this kind of macros in Nagios code. defines macro `#defined _(s) (const char*)s`  to remove warnings.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yup, it's quite popular. Since the C standard library has a very limited support for localization (it doesn't have the functionality of `gettext`), international C programs often make use of this library.

Comment: @wick you can delete your question if you wants.